# The theory of Asp.Net MVC data transmission

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I konw MVC has a lot of method to pass data,
Such as return View() would send strongly type model from controller to view.
also can use viewbag,viewdata,tempdata and so on...

I just know how to use,but what I want to figure out is how it pass data.
Can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that to understand what really happen behind the curtains, is to look at the sources of Asp.Net MVC. You can download them [here](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MVC&referringTitle=Home)

Answer (score 1):

The best method to pass data is through `Model` class , and return it `return View(model);`

Comment: He wants to know how the Framework handles the data to pass to the view.